# Do vacuum wine stoppers help preserve wine?

Tags: chemistry, alcohol

Vacuum wine stoppers are very popular, but I don't know how effective they actually are. I've been unable to find any scientific results. I have found plenty of people who have bought the products and think they "work great".

I've found plenty of companies selling the products who claim that they do something, even claiming that it "[keeps wine fresh for up to 2 weeks](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000GA3KCE)", and I've found plenty of wine blogs and posts of people who claim that the vacuum stoppers do nothing or even [deteriorate the wine further](http://www.thewinedoctor.com/advisory/buystoreopenbottles.shtml) (but there's always the chance they just don't like the idea).

The only link I've found to a research paper on the idea came from [someone taking the negative position](http://johnonwine.com/2009/12/17/friends-dont-let-friends-vacu-vin/), however the site where the research paper was suppose to be no longer exists. Does anyone here have some better data or explanation of the effectiveness of these devices?

Comment: It would improve the question if you could link to a couple of examples of people saying they work and those who says they don't. Any details about the research paper you know would help too.

Comment: I've seen a study that just uncorked some bottles and then immediately recorked with the cork that came out, a vacuum cork, a commercial cork (advertised to preserve wine) and a untouched control with no detected differences in composition of the wine. I call that test invalid though because the core reason for wine spoiling is air getting in the bottle and they didn't leave any real time for that to happen, they should have decanted a few glasses and then recorked. [dutch link to video](http://www.een.be/programmas/volt/reclametest-antiox-winestopper)